# needing more info on question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I searched for info about a programming subject.  I found several answers on SO, most of which referenced a module supposedly available on one specific web site in glowing terms.  When I tried to go there it was secured.  When I posted a question to SO about that site I was shot down.  When I tried to post to one of the answers I had found on SO, I was told "this is not a forum".  I could find no way to e-mail the SO poster.  The references to the web site in the SO questions and answers were unusable.  OK.  Since I was still interested in the referenced module, what should I have done?

Comment: Can you link to the question/answers you are referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430750/using-darren-johnstones-large-file-upload-library-with-asp-net-mvc-controllers is the question he is referring to.

Comment: I've got a similar situation with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330335/python-how-to-request-pages-from-website-that-uses-openid where the answer chosen is very vague and not obvious for all (not for me at least). I'd want more details as to how to achieve this. So how am I to do this: ask the same question again? I commented, users go online since then, but don't react. How can I bring attention to the subject and get people to participate?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through your [recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513728/steve-mills?tab=activity), it appears that you asked a new question regarding the question why the link in the orginal question was secured.  The more appropriate place to put the response would be in the comments on the orginal question.

You could have also asked another question, linking to the orginal, explaining why the responses there aren't satisfactory, and ask for solutions similar to the ones posted in the orginal question. (NOTE: I didn't see your question before it was deleted, so I don't know if this is what you did or if it was a rant)

Comment: With less than 50 rep on Stack Overflow the OP **can't** comment.

Comment: Good point. Did Robert create the comment for him then on the orginal question?  That makes sense, since there is a deleted answer showing in his activity too.

Comment: Yes - Robert converted his answer to a comment and then followed up with a helpful comment too.